# Will data be stored via parent class if abstract=False?

Tags: django-models

Currently, I read a good model inheritance tutorial article , it shows how to use abstract base class and inherit from parent to children. Here is the example in the article:

```
class ConactInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Customer(ContactInfo):
    purchase_history = models.ForeignKey('cart.Invoice')

class Staff(ContactInfo):
    bio = models.TextField()
    position = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

The author points out that data will be stored in Customer and Staff model instead of `ContactInfo` due to `abstract = True`. I am wondering a result if abstract is set to false. Will data is stored in `ContactInfo` model or any other result occurs?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not set the `abstract` field in the `Meta` class of `ConactInfo` (same as setting to `False`), then this whole setup will be termed [multiple inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#multiple-inheritance):

> Just as with Python’s subclassing, it’s possible for a Django model to
>   inherit from multiple parent models. Keep in mind that normal Python
>   name resolution rules apply. The first base class that a particular
>   name (e.g. Meta) appears in will be the one that is used; for example,
>   this means that if multiple parents contain a Meta class, only the
>   first one is going to be used, and all others will be ignored.

You can [read more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#multiple-inheritance) to understand how this change will affect your DB and *data storage*.